# It works but it has matters python

Tags: python

I wanted to know why my code doesn't have errors but works here's my code

```
word3="helloworldnicetomeetyou"
word4="munameispythonson"
a=[i+j for i in word3 for j in word4]
a.sort()

b=0
while(b<=391):
    if ("a[int(b)]" is "a[int(b)+1]"):
        del a[b]
    else:
        b = b+1
print(len(a))
```

I want to know the number of cases
how many kinds of 2-letter cases are in the combination in word 3 and word 4 
I sorted the cases and try to delete the cases in the list. There are 391 cases when I multiply the number of alphabets in word3 and 4. I hope you guys to solve this ㅠㅠㅠㅠ so sad..

Comment: If it works then what's your question? What problem are you having?

Comment: "I want to know the number of cases how many kinds of 2-letter cases are in the combination in word 3 and word 4 I sorted the cases and try to delete the cases in the list." <- I'm sorry but this is complete word salad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's alot wrong with this code.  Why are you puttng statement conditions inside `()`? Next, use a for statement instead of while. You forget to break out of the loop aswell. Finally, you don't need to double quote `a[b]` to convert it to string. Use the built in str() function. Here's a working version of the code:

```
word3="helloworldnicetomeetyou"
word4="munameispythonson"
a=[i+j for i in word3 for j in word4]
a.sort()

b=0
for x in range(0, len(a)):
    if b + 1 >= len(a):
        break 
    if a[b] == a[b + 1]:
        del a[b]
    else:
        b = b+1
print(len(a))
```

Next time, provide a trackback of the error and be really specific aswell.

Comment: Oh!! Thank you so much I really reaaaaallly appreciate your help hahah